# biblatex-chicago editor prefix formatting

Tags: biblatex, formatting, editors, biblatex-chicago

I'm currently writing my bachelor thesis (in german) and have a problem using biblatex-chicago.

Its overall running fine except a little detail i cant figure out how to fix:
When i use the german localization the footnote looks like this:

Vgl. Arno Herzig, „Die ersten Kinderarbeitsschutzgesetze in Preußen: Ursachen und Folgen“, in Straßenkinder und Kinderarbeit: sozialisationstheoretische, historische und kulturvergleichende Studien, **hrsg.** Christel Adick (Frankfurt am Main: IKO-Verlag für Interkulturelle Kommunikation, 1997), 30.

The editor "hrsg." should be either "Hrsg." or "hrsg. von" but i have no idea how to change it like that.

I really hope some kind person has a solution for this.

Comment: Does this work `\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{editor = {Hrsg.},editors = {Hrsg.}}`?
If not, please provide a MWE.

Comment: Not the exact thing but `\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{cbyeditor = {Hrsg.},editors = {Hrsg.}}` did the trick.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

You need to adjust the `cbyeditor` string to do this in `biblatex-chicago`. You may want to do this for other `cby…` strings also as in general they seem to use lowercase without *von*. See `cms-ngerman.lbx` for a list of relevant strings.

You modify strings for a particular language using the `\DefineBibliographyStrings` macro. See §3.9 of the `biblatex` manual for usage.

I don't speak German, so I hope the following MWE has set up the bib entry correctly.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{herzig:1997,
  author = {Herzig, Arno},
  title = {Die ersten Kinderarbeitsschutzgesetze in Preußen},
  subtitle = {Ursachen und Folgen},
  booktitle = {Straßenkinder und Kinderarbeit},
  booksubtitle = {sozialisationstheoretische, historische und kulturvergleichende Studien},
  editor = {Adick, Christel},
  location = {Frankfurt am Main},
  publisher = {IKO-Verlag für Interkulturelle Kommunikation},
  date = {1997}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{%
  cbyeditor = {hsrg\adddotspace von}
}
\begin{document}
\null\vfill
\autocite[\bibstring{confer}][30]{herzig:1997}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]